# .NET Core : Not Able To Automatically Redirect To HTTPS | AddRedirectToHttps

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to implement default https redirection to application-

For that in Startup.cs - Configure(..) method -

```
var opts = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();                                     
      app.UseRewriter(opts);
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Also I have port settings 443.. in launchsettings.json-

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63339",
      "sslPort": 44358
    }
  }
```

Also checked with Debug Properties -> SSL ->

[image]

Still I am not able to redirect automatically to HTTPS

Could you let me know whats missing in this?

**EDIT 1:  When url is navigated from http , I get failed request , instead of getting redirected to https -**

[image]

Comment: What _specifically_ happens? What _exact_ url are you loading? What _exact_ error are you seeing?

Comment: @mjwills please check edit1

Comment: What exact url are you loading?

Comment: can you used ```app.UseHsts();```   in configure method under else{..}?